# How to find if the tail command will work on a given file

Tags: files, tail

I let the user specify a filename say `hello.txt` and the number of newest lines say `30` they want from the file.

I then fire the below command to get them the data they are looking for.

```
tail -30f hello.txt > hello.txt.tmp; mv hello.txt.tmp hello.txt;
```

The problem is when the user provides some irrelevant file that does not have text or directory the command does not work. For example:jdk.zip

```
tail -30f jdk.zip > jdk.zip.tmp; mv jdk.zip.tmp jdk.zip;
```

The above simply never returns.

Thus, I need a solution that I should be able to check if the provided file will work with the `tail` command or not; before I fire the actual command.

Thus, a directory, a zip file, a PDF, an mp4 file, etc whichever do not work with the `tail command` should not be tailed.

I'm on Linux system.

Comment: maybe use `file <your-file>`, look for ASCII text, or some UTF/latin/... encoding.

Comment: Also note that tail -f will never terminate by itself when reading a file (it will terminate if reading a pipe). It also won't get anything new unless another process is appending to the file. And if you do Ctrl_C it, or send it a signal, it might not flush the last block of the file (the man page says nothing about that situation).

Comment: Can you confirm that you use `-f` with `tail` in both cases and that it works the same way as `-n 30 -f` does, and that one of the commands is doing what you want while the other is not?

Comment: I have discarded using `-f` with `tail` as it never completes. The link shared by @pLumo helped. We can use ansible `stat` module to meet my requirement.